# Python for managing multiple Network Devices

Tags: python, automation

I'm trying to get

1. Apply a `ping` command to the network devices from `.csv` file and taking that output for more than 100 network devices and store the output in one specific file at one particular location.
2. Take various show commands especially :
   `Sh Version, Sh run | i logging, Sh run | i snmp` etc.
   on more than 100s of network devices and store the output properly at one specific location.
3. Apply specific lists of commands from the `.txt` file for the 100s of network devices that listed in `.csv` files.

Using python:

- Does anyone have any advice how should I start?
- I have seen many old posts where the person have displayed the entire code, but I need to know how I can pick them up from the `.csv` files from my own computer.

Comment: While not an answer to the question, I would totally use ansible for this... it really is well suited for these kinds of operations. Also ansible is python based, so if there is not a plugin / module that does what you need, it is fairly easy to implement your own.

Comment: To further expand on my previous comment on using ansible... Cisco has been notorious for having really crappy standardization when it comes to non-printing characters, such as /r /n /t and <space> with major changes in minor patch fixes, and lack of consistency between platforms. Before ansible, and nso etc, most automation was done with custom expect files stolen and modified for each plaform from an application called rancid. Today I automate Network devices full time, I would not ever recommend trying to roll your own.

Comment: Thank You James, Do you have any advice how should I start in this direction?

Comment: I would recommend starting here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/index.html

There are also a lot of conference talks from NANOG and CISCO Live you might be able to find.

Comment: Thank You, James

Comment: @PythonCurious , also follow the links on https://www.networktocode.com/community/ to see their GitHub projects/Slack community and check out https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko as well. netmiko will let you SSH to a network device with Python - it's probably the easiest way to do this if you don't want to use Ansible ( and you should totally try Ansible too)